# Silverlight 4 Out of Browser: "Unable to determine the URL to the Xap file from web"

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

For some reason, whenever I now try and run my SL4 application out-of-browser, when I run it I get the following message:

"Unable to determine the URL to the Xap file from web "

refers to an old name of my web project, and it has now been renamed. I've gone through all references of said project name and can't find any more; clearly it's getting it from somewhere though!

Googled but found nothing (aside from a link to an SO question which is now removed!).

Any help gratefully received...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue comes from a misconfiguration of the project's user file. VS can't find which XAP file it should use during the debugging experience.

In the myproject.csproj.user file, change

```
<OutOfBrowserProjectToDebug>OldName</OutOfBrowserProjectToDebug>
```

to

```
<OutOfBrowserProjectToDebug>NewName</OutOfBrowserProjectToDebug>
```

Comment: excellent - thank you :-) that explains why find-in-files didn't work to find that reference to the old project name - the .user file isn't a part of the visual studio solution.

Comment: Note: You'll have to reload your VS Solution/Project to pick up the change if you modify the user file manually (via notepad, for example)

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight 5 and Visual Studio 2012:

- go to silverlight project settings, open `Debug` tab and click on combobox, then select  existing value. Usually there will be only one item (already selected), but it's important to click on it.

[image: ScreenShot]